# Impact of Bandwidth Increase on Shannon Capacity

Tags: wireless, bandwidth, capacity

What is the impact of doubling of bandwidth on Shannon Capacity, assuming noise power spectral density and signal power remain the same?

Comment: Do you know the Shannon-Hartley channel capacity formula?

Comment: My Cable Modem uses 24x 5MHz bands every 6MHz and each is received at >= 37 dB SNR using QAM256. What is my Channel Capacity? at 400 Mbps downlink rate what is the expected BER?  If you understand this , then you will appreciate Shannon Capacity more

Comment: 37dB SNR on linear scale is 5012. So the capacity can be calculated as C=24*5e6*log2(1+5012)=1475Mbps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the statement of the Shannon-Hartley Theorem, which gives a *theoretical* bound on the channel capacity<sup>1</sup>:

$$C = B \log_2\left(1+\frac{S}{N}\right)$$

Under your assumptions, the bandwidth doubles, while the noise PSD stays the same. This means that the noise power roughly doubles (in practice the performance of the bandpass filter is also relevant here). Because you're dealing with an unchanged signal power, you're now looking at:

$$C^\prime = 2B \log_2\left(1+\frac{S}{2N}\right)$$

Note that for all possible (i.e. positive real) SNR values, \$C^\prime \geq C\$. However, note that \$C' \neq 2C\$ (see [interactive graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3yfsrxruv2)). However, \$C'/C\$ does approach 2 as SNR increases, very slowly (e.g. at 90 dB SNR, the ratio is 1.933).

<sup>1</sup> A practical realization of a communication channel may not necessarily realize the theoretical bound, or may only realize it asymptotically.

Comment: @YasirAhmed Doubling occurs at higher SNR, not lower SNR: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3yfsrxruv2

Comment: Very good explanation, I really wanted to highlight that doubling of bandwidth does not mean doubling of capacity, unless you are operating at very high SNR